Session not persisting in PHP
EDIT: I know that normally the passwords need to be hashed and not plaintext. This specific assignment doesn't care about that. This isn't for a real website, it's just for learning how to deal with sessions and persistence.
ORIGINAL:
I really need some help with this. I can't for the life of me figure out why the session is not persisting in my code. I have tried following the examples I've seen, but no dice. If I click on the "Home" link, it's supposed to stay on the same page but still keep the file open because it's still supposed to be signed in. However, it just takes me back to the login form. Same thing when I click in the address bar and hit enter. I'm also having the issue where the code that tells the page to just display the form if the session isn't running just causes the page to keep redirecting until I get an error page. Please help!
    <?php
    session_start();

    //MAKE SOME CONSTANTS
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') {
    //PRIVATE
    }    
    else {
    //PRIVATE
    }

    //CONNECT TO DB
    function connectToDatabase() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        return $conn;
    }

    //CHECK AGAINST USERNAMES AND PASSWORDS IN DB
    function checkUserNameAndPassword($username, $password) {
        $conn = connectToDatabase();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

            $_SESSION['granted'] = true;
            setcookie('name', $username, time() + 3600);

            //NAV BAR
            echo '<div class="navbar">';
            echo '<a href=".">Home</a>';
            echo '<a href="?logout=true">Logout</a>';
            echo '</div>';

            //SUCCESSFUL FORM
            echo '<div class="form">';
            echo '<div class="access">';
            echo 'ACCESS GRANTED';
            echo '</div>';

            //READ FILE
            $fileContents = file_get_contents("includes/fbi.txt");
            $lines = explode('||>><<||', $fileContents);

                
            //TABLE
            echo '<div class="table">';
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th class="title">Agent</th><th class="title">Code Name</th>';
            echo '</tr>';

            //LOOP THROUGH FILE
            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                $pair = explode(',', $line);
                $agent = ucfirst($pair[0]);
                $codename = ($pair[1]);

                //DEALING WITH TWO WORD CODENAMES
                if (strpos($codename, ' ') !== false) {
                    $words = explode(' ', $codename);
                    foreach ($words as &$word) {
                        $word = ucfirst($word);
                    }
                    $codename = implode(' ', $words);
                }
                else {
                    $codename = ucfirst($codename);
                }

                //INSERT INFO TO TABLE
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $agent . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $codename . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else {
            //UNSUCCESSFUL FORM
            echo '<div class="form">';
            echo '<div class="access">';
            echo 'ACCESS DENIED<br>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo 'Please enter valid credentials.';
            echo '<form method="post" name="logIn">';
            echo '<input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="userName"><br><br>';
            echo '<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"><br><br>';
            echo '<div class="submit">';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="sub-button">';
            echo '<input type="reset" name="reset-button">';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        
        //CLOSE CONNECTION
        $conn->close();

    }

    function isGranted() {
        return $_SESSION['granted'];
    }

    //LOGOUT FUNCTIONALITY
    if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 'true') {
        //CLEAR SESSION VARIABLES
        $_SESSION = array();
    
        //DESTROY SESSION
        session_destroy();
    
        //REDIRECT
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = $_POST['userName'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            checkUserNameAndPassword($username, $password);
            //$_SESSION['granted'] = true;
            //setcookie('name', $username, time() + 3600);
        }
    }

    //if (!isset($_SESSION['granted']) || !$_SESSION['granted']) {
    //    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    //    exit;
    //}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Insecure Passwords</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $result->num_rows != 1)) {
    ?>        
        <div class="form">
            <form method="post" name="logIn">
                <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="userName"><br><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"><br><br>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="sub-button">
                    <input type="reset" name="reset-button">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>

I can't figure out where the $_SESSION['granted'] = true line or isGranted function could go to fix the problem. Or if that even is the problem.

It might help to step back and write a minimal page without the database that just has fake login ( like checking user == "john && password == "apple") and logout.  Get the session handling working first, then add the real login.  Also, for a real website you want to use password_hash not plain text, and your SQL needs to be using parameterized queries to make SQL injection less likely.  For development turn on errors and warnings, and you can dump variables to the output to see what is going on.

neither  $_SESSION['granted'] or isGranted function can be seen used. And as far as I can see, this code is supposed to show login form every time it's called

@YourCommonSense I'm confused about how $_SESSION['granted'] isn't seen being used. It's in the beginning of the function checkUserNameAndPassword right under the first "if" statement. I've also tried putting it in the section regarding the server method right after the checkUserNameAndPassword function is called. Neither one seems to work. Before I tried adding the persistence (the assignment is to make the previous assignment persistent) the page worked just fine, only showing the form when the usernames and passwords were wrong and showing the file when they were correct.

This is how you assign it. But then you don't use it anywhere

When working with login scripts, to grant users permission to see behind the "wall" - there are a few things that you have to consider.

If security is important, and it should be, your method of validating a request to your website should include some code to prevent users from simply setting a cookie to "Y" to be "logged in".  Perhaps you provide the user a cookie that contains a hash value that the backend then checks?

setting the $_SESSION variable, does not necessarily mean that it will be there across pages (See timeout value for $_SESSION).

Using plaintext passwords in your database should not be a thing.  You should hash the passwords / and store them such that they are not in plaintext.

Finally, your page appears to use the POST values to detect if a user is logged in or not, or is logging in.  In this case, once the user has logged in, and then refreshes the page, the page detects that nothing is set for POST, and requests the login again.  You probably want to check your cookie value for 'name' or your $_SESSION value for 'granted', rather than POST.  (All other security issues aside).


The code can be changed from:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $result->num_rows != 1)) {
To
if (($_SESSION['name'] ?? FALSE) === FALSE) {...

This is more a general review than answer to the question.

Please see #4, which contains the answer.

If I do that, it does log me in and keep me in, but then I'm just staring at a blank page. At this point my brain is so fried from dealing with this that have no idea what to do to even fix that.

Sounds like the above solved your specific issue.  Happy to help.
As to the blank page - I am sure a bit of coding with an else statement to execute if logged in would work.  But, it sounds like you might benefit from some training / classes in PHP to take this where you want to go. @WastelandSniper
